# Constrained minimization failing to compute general solution despite giving solution for specific inputs

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am trying to run

```
Minimize[{a^2/2*(x^2 - x) + b^2/2*(y^2 - y) + c^2/2*(z^2 - z) + 
   i*a*b*x*y + j*a*c*x*z + k*b*c*y*z, x + y + z == 1, x >= 0, y >= 0, 
  z >= 0, a >= 0, b >= 0, c >= 0, i >= 0, j >= 0, k >= 0, i <= 1, 
  j <= 1, k <= 1}, {x, y, z}]
```

This will time out before giving a solution, but if I provide it with specific numerical values for $a,b,c$ and $i,j,k$ it will quickly compute the required choices for $x,y,z$. Is there something I can change to make Mathematica find the general solution?

Comment: Probably not simply. You may be able to coax it to give you a better solution by manipulating the expression, but it seems pretty complicated. This would be a great use of numerics, in that the numerical solution is calculated very fast once you have numbers.